# Performing K-fold Cross-Validation: Using Same Training Set vs. Separate Validation Set

Tags: validation, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using the Python scikit-learn framework to build a decision tree. I am currently splitting my training data into two separate sets, one for training and the other for validation (implemented via K-fold cross-validation).

To cross-validate my model, should I split my data into two sets as outlined above or simply use the full training set? My main objective is to prevent overfitting. I have seen conflicting answers online about the use and efficacy of both these approaches.

I understand that K-fold cross-validation is commonly used when there is not enough data for a separate validation set. I do not have this limitation. Intuitively speaking, I believe that employing K-fold cross-validation in conjunction with a separate dataset will further reduce overfitting.

Is my supposition correct? Is there a better approach I can use to validate my model?

**Split Dataset Approach:**

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[features], df["SeriousDlqin2yrs"], test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
dt.fit(x_train, y_train)

scores = cross_val_score(dt, x_test, y_test, cv=10)
```

**Training Dataset Approach:**

```
x_train=df[features]
y_train=df["SeriousDlqin2yrs"]

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
dt.fit(x_train, y_train)

scores = cross_val_score(dt, x_train, y_train, cv=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems that you are very confused by both validating as well as what `cross_val_score` does. First thing first, you should not do any of the above approaches. If you are **not searching for some hyperparameters**, but instead just want to answer the question *"How good is DT with min_samples_split=20 on my data"*, then you should do:

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
scores = cross_val_score(dt, X, y, cv=10)
```

Without **any splitting**. Why? Because `cross_val_score` does the splitting. What it does, it splits the `X` and `y` into 10 parts and performs 10 times fitting on trianing and then testing on remaining part. In other words if you do something like

```
x_train=df[features]
y_train=df["SeriousDlqin2yrs"]

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
dt.fit(x_train, y_train) # this line does nothing!

scores = cross_val_score(dt, x_train, y_train, cv=10)
```

Then `fit` command is useless, as cross_val_score will call fit again, 10 times. Furthermore here you do not use `test` set at all! Similarly in your second code - you would both fit, and test on test set, also incorrect.

However, **if you are trying to fit some hyperparameter**, lets say this min_samples_split, then you should (assuming that your test set is big enough to be representible):

```
X_train, y_train = X[train], y[train]
X_test, y_test = X[test], y[test]

scores = []
for param in [10, 20, 40]:
   dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=param, random_state=99)
   scores.append((cross_val_score(dt, X_train, y_train, cv=10), param))

best_param = max(scores)[1]
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=best_param, random_state=99)
print np.mean(dt.predict(X_test)==y_test) # checking accuracy on testing set
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks, it was a very enlightening answer. Still a beginner, a lot of work to do.